# Where could I find the House of Representatives voting record for the Export Administration Act of 1979?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, voting-records

When did the House approve the Export Administration Act described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Administration_Act_of_1979)?

This [proposed](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/votes/96-1979/h462) bill, The Export Administration Act, was rejected by the House on 9/25/79.  So there must be another time when the House voted on the bill.

I would like to know when the House passed the bill and which Representatives voted for and against it.  Where can I find the voting record of this bill as it eventually passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When did the House approve the Export Administration Act described here?

[TO AGREE TO THE CONFERENCE REPORT ON S. 737, A BILL PROVIDING AUTHORITY TO REGULATE EXPORTS. (MOTION PASSED).](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/votes/96-1979/h475), Sep 28, 1979.

S. 737 (96th): Export Administration Act of 1979.

---

The proposed bill was to remove *RESTRICTIONS ON THE SALE OF ALASKAN CRUDE OIL*.

The ban was lifted by [H.R.2029 — 114th Congress (2015-2016)](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/2029):

> ... end the ban on U.S. crude oil exports; ...

The [House vote](http://clerk.house.gov/evs/2015/roll193.xml) was 255 to 163.

The [Senate vote](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_lists/roll_call_vote_cfm.cfm?congress=114&session=1&vote=00339) was 65 to 33.

---

The text of H.R.2029 refers to the Energy Policy and Conservation Act (EPCA), not to the Export Administration Act of 1979.

Wikipedia, [Energy Policy and Conservation Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Policy_and_Conservation_Act), in particular [Crude oil export ban, 1977-2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Policy_and_Conservation_Act#Crude_oil_export_ban,_1977-2015).

> On December 18, 2015 Congress lifted the 41 year old ban. Republicans favored lifting the ban and in return agreed to not block a $500m payment to the UN Green Climate Fund and tax breaks for solar and wind power.

Comment: When did the House pass the Export Trade Administration Act in 1979?  Do you know the month and day?

Comment: @HarleyC. - [History](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/96/s737), PUBLIC LAW 96-72—SEPT. 29, 1979. Senate, JUL 21, 1979.  House, SEP 25, 1979.

Comment: My link in the original question shows the House voted on 9/25/19.  The link you most recently posted has a "History" section near the bottom of the page.  It concurs with my 9/25/19 date for when the House voted on it.  (But this vote of the House on this bill was a "No" leading to rejection.  When I look at your main answer, I see the House voted on 9/28/19.  When did the House vote to approve it?

Comment: @HarleyC. - Wikipedia, [Export Administration Act of 1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Administration_Act_of_1979), provides the Legislative history on the right. The link is to  [S.737](https://www.congress.gov/bill/96th-congress/senate-bill/00737/actions). On 9/28/1979 the _House agreed to conference report, roll call #523 (321-19)_. However, the roll call number should be 475, as given in my answer. Note also 9/25/1979  _Measure passed House, amended, in lieu of H. R. 4034._ H.R.4034 died, S.737 with amendments became law.